# nested List Compare Equals

Tags: c#, list, c#-4.0, collections

I have this C# class

```
 public class EntryClass
    {
        public string Field { get; set; }
        public List<FieldKeyValuePair<string, string>> FieldKeyValPairs { get; set; }

        public bool Equals(EntryClass other)
        {
            return Field.Equals(other.Field)
                && FieldKeyValPairs.Equals(other.FieldKeyValPairs);
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
            if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
            if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
            return Equals((EntryClass)obj);

        }
    }

    public class FieldKeyValuePair<K, V>
    {
        public K Key { get; set; }
        public V Value { get; set; }

        public bool Equals(FieldKeyValuePair<K, V> other)
        {
            return Key.Equals(other.Key)
                && Value.Equals(other.Value);
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
            if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
            if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
            return Equals((FieldKeyValuePair<K, V>)obj);
        }

    }
```

trying to do `Assert.IsTrue(expected.SequenceEqual(actual));` always gives me false, I am seeing that even when expected and actual has same FieldKeyValPairs this expression always hits false  `&& FieldKeyValPairs.Equals(other.FieldKeyValPairs);`

**EDIT**
And expected and Actual is of type

```
 List<EntryClass> expected = new List<EntryClass>(); // TODO: 
         List<EntryClass> actual = new List<EntryClass>();
```

Comment: He is explaining well enough, but its a formatting problem. His problem is described at the end of the code sample he provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change
          return Field.Equals(other.Field)
                && FieldKeyValPairs.Equals(other.FieldKeyValPairs);

TO

```
      return Field.Equals(other.Field)
            && FieldKeyValPairs.SequenceEqual(other.FieldKeyValPairs);
```

Answer (score 2):

May be you just forgot to override GetHashCode(). Some comparison algorithm compares the hash code first to speed up the computation.

See this answer for more info:
[Why is it important to override GetHashCode when Equals method is overridden?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371328/why-is-it-important-to-override-gethashcode-when-equals-method-is-overridden)

Comment: I did forget that i added them but still i am noticing that when         return Field.Equals(other.Field)
                && FieldKeyValPairs.Equals(other.FieldKeyValPairs); executes it is not hitting the equals override for this class FieldKeyValPairs

Comment: @Justin You should add more unit tests to test every methods independently. May be you could start with testing the FieldKeyValuePair.Equals function directly instead of testing them through a list comparison.